# Outliers Detection

Tags: python, outliers, anomaly-detection

The outliers in this example was generated by me

The graph bellow represents the readings from one device, in the same day over multiple weeks, normal values in purple, red values are outliers, which means values that stands out from the normal pattern

I have already tried iforest, ocsvm and few others

And after messing around with those i was unable to reproduce the ocsvm that showed the best result (3rd plot), i might have lost some parameters

[image: i have already tried iforest and svm and few others]

What would be the best algorithm for detecting such outliers?

Dataset

```
index   day interval    device  nv_zscore   c_faulty    c_normal
0   0   0   0   -1.308137   0   1
1   0   1   0   -1.330926   0   1
2   0   2   0   -1.285348   0   1
3   0   3   0   -1.253444   0   1
4   0   4   0   -1.194192   0   1
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
67195   6   19  9   0.882879    1   0
67196   6   20  9   1.544848    1   0
67197   6   21  9   0.147239    1   0
67198   6   22  9   0.674702    1   0
67199   6   23  9   -0.306257   1   0
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean with outliers? Could you please clarify your question.

Comment: Ok, but why is the ocsvm the best? By which metric do you judge?

Comment: It showed the closest results to the original

Comment: Ok, I think you think to complicated with iforest and ocsvm. To me I looks like the original just takes the mean at a given x-coordinate and filters the values that are some amount out. Something like if the deviation is 15 % of the mean, you get a outlier. If you look at it it looks a lot like a boxplot like distribution, at least for me. I know thats no solution, but maybe you could try, just taking the mean and marking some amount of values blue and the rest red.

Comment: in fact that's the method i used to generate the outliers, but it was only suitable for this situation, and so i am using an ml approach to be more general

Comment: I now understand your question XD. I think iforest and ocsvm are the wrong approach in this case, because they are designed as 2 dim algorithms and you do not exactly have that in this case. I would search for a 1 dim algo that you apply recursively at every x -coordinate.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Will a time series algorithm work ?

Comment: I dont know how you would implement a time series algorithm, because it just predicts the next value and you still would use standard deviation to filter outliers. I think your original statistical approach wasn´t that flawed.

Comment: But a ml algo that uses two mathematical sets as input for the axis would be very interesting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245593/discussion-between-awovu-netux-and-poder-psittacus).